# Is there a name for a biharmonic equation with an extra set of squared mixed partials?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, terminology, finite-differences

I've run into the following PDE, defined on a rectangle:
$$
\nabla^4 \psi + \alpha\:\partial^2_x\partial^2_y\psi = f(x, y)
$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant. It takes on the following values at the boundaries:
$$
\psi = 0 \\
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n} = 0
$$
with $\partial/\partial n$ denoting the derivative normal to the boundary.
Every biharmonic equation solver I can find solves an equation of the form:
$$
\nabla^4\psi + \alpha\nabla^2\psi + \beta \psi = f(x, y)
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. I'm wondering whether the first PDE has a name so that I can investigate premade numerical solvers. If not, might there be a way to extend typical numerical biharmonic solvers to work with the extra mixed derivative term? I have been looking at finite difference solvers, but it's not clear to me how dependent on the specific details of the equation these algorithms are.

Comment: Please, add some info about the $(x,y)$ domain. Is it square? Also is $\alpha$ some fixed constant or depend itself on $x, y$?

Comment: @uranix rectangle not square, and yes they're constants. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: If you are looking for computational solvers, I would suggest using the [Dedalus project](http://dedalus-project.org/) code. It's very much a 'plug and play' spectral numerical solver and could easily handle your problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question. But it seems that some finite-difference solvers for biharmonic equation in rectangular domain are not hard to extend so they can handle this type of equation too.

This problem is attractive because it has constant coefficients and is defined on a rectangular domain. Such problems are often directly solvable by FFT methods. And if you google for *direct solver for biharmonic equation on a rectangle* you'll get a couple of papers. [This one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220412193_A_Fast_Direct_Solver_for_the_Biharmonic_Problem_in_a_Rectangular_Grid) is particularly interesting. In addition to the method itself this work gives a great overview of existing methods for biharmonic problem in 2D.

Let's try to adapt one of them to your problem. First, let's rewrite the equation a bit
$$
\left[
\partial_x^4 + (2 + \alpha) \partial_x^2 \partial_y^2 + \partial_y^4
\right] u = f(x, y), \qquad (x, y) \in G = [0, L_x] \times [0, L_y]\\
\left.u\right|_{G} = 0, \qquad \left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right|_{G} = 0.
$$
Introduce a regular grid in $G$:
$$
x_i = i h_x, \; i = -1, 0, \dots, N_x, N_x + 1, \quad h_x = \frac{L_x}{N_x}\\
y_j = j h_y, \; j = -1, 0, \dots, N_y, N_y + 1, \quad h_y = \frac{L_y}{N_y}
$$
The nodes $i = -1$, $j = -1$, $i = N_x + 1$, $j = N_y + 1$ lie outside of the domain $G$. They allow to simplify the approximation of the boundary conditions $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right|_{G} = 0$.

The approximated boundary conditions take the form
$$
u_{0,j} = u_{N_x,j} = u_{i,0} = u_{i,N_y} = 0\\
\frac{u_{1,j} - u_{-1,j}}{2h_x} = 
\frac{u_{N_x + 1,j} - u_{N_x - 1,j}}{2h_x} = 0\\
\frac{u_{i,1} - u_{i,-1}}{2h_y} = 
\frac{u_{i,N_y+1} - u_{i,N_y-1}}{2h_y} = 0\\
$$
Boundary condition express external (to domain $G$) unknowns via internal ones. The rest $(N_x - 1) (N_y - 1)$ values are unknown. Each internal node has an associated difference equation
$$
\frac{u_{i-2,j} -4 u_{i-1,j} + 6u_{i,j} -4 u_{i+1,j} + u_{i+2,j}}{h_x^4} + \\
(2 + \alpha) \frac{u_{i-1,j-1} - 2u_{i-1,j} + u_{i-1,j+1} -2 u_{i,j-1} + 4u_{i,j} -2u_{i,j+1}+u_{i+1,j-1} - 2u_{i+1,j} + u_{i+1,j+1}}{h_x^2 h_y^2} + \\
\frac{u_{i,j-2} -4 u_{i,j-1} + 6u_{i,j} -4 u_{i,j+1} + u_{i,j+2}}{h_y^4} = f_{i,j} \equiv f(x_i, y_j)
$$

Let's introduce some matrices:
$$
\Lambda_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&1 & -2 & 1\\
&&&1 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\Lambda_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
7 & -4 & 1\\
-4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
&&&1 & -4 & 6 & -4\\
&&&&1 & -4 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
They are obtained by eliminating external and boundary unknowns using boundary conditions from the finite difference operators of second and fourth derivative. Using these operators the difference problem might be written shorter:
$$
\left[
\frac{1}{h_x^4} \Lambda_4 \otimes I + 
\frac{2 + \alpha}{h_x^2 h_y^2} \Lambda_2 \otimes \Lambda_2 + 
\frac{1}{h_y^4} I \otimes \Lambda_4\right] U = F
$$
Here $A \otimes B$ stands for a direct product of operator $A$ acting along $x$ directions and $B$ acting along $y$ direction.

Consider [discrete sine transform of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform#DST-I) which is a FFT-family transform.
$$
x_n = \sqrt\frac{2}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} X_k \sin \frac{\pi kn}{N}, \qquad
X_k = \sqrt\frac{2}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} x_n \sin \frac{\pi kn}{N}, \qquad
$$
The matrix $\mathbb F$ of size $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ defined as
$$
\mathbb F = \left[\sqrt\frac{2}{N} \sin \frac{\pi kn}{N}\right]_{kn}
$$
diagnolizes $\Lambda_2$ and almost diagnolizes $\Lambda_4$. Also $\mathbb F^{-1} = \mathbb F^\top = \mathbb F$. The DST basis consists of functions
$$
\psi^{(k)} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\begin{pmatrix}
\sin \frac{\pi k}{N}&
\sin \frac{2 \pi k}{N}&
\dots&
\sin \frac{(N-2) \pi k}{N}&
\sin \frac{(N-1) \pi k}{N}
\end{pmatrix}^\top.
$$
$$
\Lambda_2 \psi^{(k)} = \lambda_k \psi^{(k)}\\
\lambda_k = -4 \sin^2 \frac{\pi k}{2N}.
$$
Vectors $\psi^{(k)}$ are also eigenvectors for matrix
$$
\Lambda_4^{C} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & -4 & 1\\
-4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
&&&1 & -4 & 6 & -4\\
&&&&1 & -4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalues $\mu_k = \lambda_k^2$. Denote $R = \Lambda_4 - \Lambda_4^C = \operatorname{diag}[2, 0, \dots, 0, 2]$.

The problem changes to
$$
\left[
\underbrace{\frac{1}{h_x^4} \Lambda_4^C \otimes I + 
\frac{2 + \alpha}{h_x^2 h_y^2} \Lambda_2 \otimes \Lambda_2 + 
\frac{1}{h_y^4} I \otimes \Lambda_4^C}_{A,\text{ diagonalizable by }\mathbb F}
+ \underbrace{
\frac{1}{h_x^4} R \otimes I + 
\frac{1}{h_y^4} I \otimes R
}_{B,\text{ low rank perturbation}}
\right] U = F
$$

Introduce $W = \mathbb F \otimes \mathbb F$ - the matrix of the 2D DST transform.
$$
A = W D W, \quad D = \operatorname{diag}[d_{i,j}]\\
d_{i,j} = \frac{(\mu_x)_i}{h_x^4}
+ \frac{2 + \alpha}{h_x^2 h_y^2} (\lambda_x)_i (\lambda_y)_j
+ \frac{(\mu_y)_j}{h_y^4}.
$$
If we didn't have the perturbation term the solution to $AU = F$ may be obtained in the following steps:

1. Perform 2D DST of $F$.
2. Divide obtained DST coefficients by $d_{i,j}$ elementwise.
3. Perform inverse 2D DST (which is the same as 2D DST) and it would be the solution $U$.

The perturbation term makes things more complicated. One approach is using the [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity):
$$
(A + VV^\top)^{-1} F = A^{-1} F -
A^{-1} V (I + V^\top A^{-1} V)^{-1} V^\top A^{-1} F.
$$
Here $VV^\top = B$ and $V = (V_1\; V_2)$ where
$$
V_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{h_x^2} \begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix} \otimes I, \quad
V_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{h_y^2} I \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Matrices $V_1$ and $V_2$ practically extract $x$ and $y$ near to boundary values out of 2D array (up to scale factor).

The complexity of direct application of the Woodbury formula is in inversion of the capacitance matrix $I + V^\top A^{-1}V$.
The simplest approach is to compute $(I + V^\top A^{-1}V)^{-1} r$ iteratively as a solution of
$$
(I + V^\top A^{-1}V)s = r.
$$
The matrix is s.p.d. so we might use conjugate gradients to compute the solution. The only function CG need is matrix-vector product, $s \mapsto (I + V^\top A^{-1}V)s$. This matrix-vector product is roughly as hard as computing $A^{-1} g$ which may be done by the algorithm for unperturbed system above.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/uranix/2e6d0184c29caac39d07583e36c40f42) is the implementation of this algorithm in python.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Just a few questions: here are we saying that $r \equiv V^\top A^{-1} F$? And if so, is the next step to compute $A^{-1} F$ by the DST method and then sparse matrix multiply by $V^\top$ to find $r$? Then calculate $A^{-1} V s$ similarly? I just ask because it seems like we are having to compute $A^{-1} g$ and $V h$ for various $g$'s and $h$'s a few times and I want to make sure all are necessary. Also I think there is a small typo in the first equation -- should be $\partial_x^2 \partial_y^2$ for the second term.

Comment: We once compute $A^{-1}F$, store it and use twice. Also there are several computations of $A^{-1}g$ with different $g$ arising from CG iterations. Also multiplying with $A{-1}$ (solving) is performed as the last step of evaluating the second term in Woodbury's formula. In fact no sparse matrix is necessary, multiplication with $V$ and $V^T$ is simply extracting boundaries from 2D array and putting them back (take a look at V_matvec, VT_matvec routines)

Comment: I am struggling to see how $VV^\top = B$ as defined here. I calculated $B$ to be something which just returns the edges of the $U$ matrix (x-, y-edges scaled appropriately) with zeros for all the internal grid points. When I try to calculate $V = (V_1 V_2)$ I get that $V = 2/h_x^2 h_y^2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &... &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &... &0 &1 \end{pmatrix}^\top \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &... &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &... &0 &1 \end{pmatrix}^\top$ which gives $VV^\top = 4/h_x^4 h_y^4 (\text{diag}[1, 0, ..., 0, 1] \otimes \text{diag}[1, 0, ..., 0, 1])$. Am I misunderstanding some notation?

Comment: @LucasMyers $V$ is not a product of $V_1$ and $V_2$, but a side-by-side concatenation.

Comment: One more question: when you introduce these external nodes outside the domain then solve for them using the normal derivative condition, that is accurate to order 2, correct? How does that order 2 approximation interact with the order 2 approximations used in the $\Lambda_2$ and $\Lambda_4$ operators? That is, does adding these external nodes reduce the accuracy at all?

Comment: Yes, external nodes are used to maintain second order accurate normal derivative. The $\Delta^2 + ...$ operator is also using second order approximations. Then external nodes are eliminated from the linear system, altering the coefficients in $\Lambda_2$ and $\Lambda_4$. The overall second order approximation remains after this elimination. In fact $\Lambda_2$ and $\Lambda_4$ are not second order approximation for arbitrary functions, but only for those that satisfy boundary conditions.